# True behaviour of the instruction ADD ESP 4

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

As far as I've understood, adding 4 (or potentially 8) bytes to your stack pointer will essentially erase the previous value from the stack without putting it into a register like `pop`. But the stack and the stack pointer are two different things.

- Does this mean that you actually do not erase the value, but just erase the pointer position so that it's going to act as if it's empty?
- Does this mean you also could `SUB ESP, 4` and retrieve the data even after "erasing" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] adding four[32-bit] (or potentially eight[64-bit]) bytes to your stack pointer will essentially erase the previous value from the stack without putting it into a register like pop.

The stack is a LIFO data-structure, so the last value put on the stack would be removed first. Adding a value of 4(8) bytes to the stack just skips the current top-most value without transferring it to a register. `POP` would transfer the value to register, too.

> Does this mean that you actually do not erase the value, but just erase the pointer position so that it's going to act as if it's empty?

You let just point the *Top-Of-The-Stack-Pointer* ESP(RSP) to the previous entry. The current entry is not erased, but skipped (not pointed to anymore).

> Does this mean you also could SUB ESP 4 and retrieve the data even after "erasing" it?

Essentially, yes. Unless the stack has been modified by another procedure, an interrupt handler, an asynchronous call or another influence that did make use of the stack, you can retrieve the previous value of the stack. This is especially important for security aspects. So to securely erase data on the stack, it has to be overwritten by zeros manually.

Inspired by a comment from @PeterCordes I wrote a simple example in Linux 32-bit assembly illustrating this:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global _start
.text

_start:
    call subroutine
    mov  ebx, [esp-12]  /* Get data from subroutine */
    mov  eax, 1 
    int  0x80
    /* echo $? outputs '66' */

subroutine:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push 66  /* local variable to be leaked */
    mov esp, ebp    
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Name it `stack.s` and assemble it with

```
as -32 stack.s
ld -m elf_i386 -elf -o a a.out
./a
echo $?
```

The output will be `66`, the value of the local variable from the subroutine. So data leakage from the stack is possible. How serious this is? I'm not sure. But it's possible.

If you zero-out critical data, you have to take care that the compiler doesn't optimize away these instructions. You can find an one hour long lecture called ["35C3 - Memsad"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WzjAKABSDk) about this on YouTube (It's a recent talk from the german [CCC](https://www.ccc.de/)).

Comment: No 32-bit calling convention has a red-zone that guarantees the safety of anything below ESP.  It can be clobbered asynchronously.  But that's very rare in user-space, only Unix signal handlers AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I added an example of what I meant to my answer.

Comment: I was replying to your absolute statement that *Unless you have called another procedure that did make use of the stack, you can retrieve the previous value of the stack.*  That's not always true in the general case, because things are allowed to asynchronously clobber space below ESP.  The calling convention does not *guarantee* it will work *every* time.  It will almost always work, especially in user-space, if you re-read a few instructions later (so for security reasons it can be a good idea to zero even stack memory).  But you mistakenly say the value's *always* there.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ok. I changed this sentence to a more general version. If this is not ok for you, feel free to create a better formulation.

Answer (score 4):

An interrupt, context switch, or something similar may save data on the stack, overwriting any data below ESP, but until this happens, the data on the stack is not changed externally to your program. If your program pushes something onto the stack, or makes a call, then that will overwrite the data that was below ESP before the push or call.

Comment: In user-space on a multitasking OS, only Unix signal handlers can clobber space below ESP.  It's not guaranteed by any ABI or calling convention, but in practice that's the only mechanism.  On the kernel stack, though, yes all the things you mentioned can clobber stuff below the stack asynchronously.

Comment: @PeterCordes - what about various versions of Windows and where is machine state saved on a context switch?

Comment: Does Win9x do that on a user-space stack?  I know it doesn't really try to protect the kernel from user-space privilege-escalation.  I should have said "on a multitasking multi-user OS", i.e. with a kernel that stops user-space from taking over ring0 by having another user-space thread modify saved kernel state on the user-space stack.  i.e. modern OSes *must* use separate kernel stacks.  The scheduler is kernel code, it only runs when in kernel space with ESP pointing to the kernel stack (assuming separate kernel stacks).  After a context switch, you restore kernel state, then return to user.

Comment: @rcgldr: In general; for 80x86 any change to a higher privilege level (e.g. from "user" at CPL=3 to "kernel" at CPL=0) causes a stack switch, and kernel ends up using a completely different stack (and different value for `esp`) than user-space used. Sadly, there's one case where this isn't true - the `syscall` instruction doesn't change to "kernel stack" itself and creates a massive amount of pain for kernel developers (including several flavors of potential security disaster) because an interrupt (e.g. NMI) can occur before the kernel has a chance to correct  `esp`/`rsp` itself.